# Output looped PIWIK API call to CSV

Tags: node.js, matomo

I've got the following problem: I am looping through API calls using different dates to append the output to a CSV file. However, the output data in the CSV file only contains data from the first date.

When I log the results to the command prompt I do get multiple dates, meaning the problem occurs when writing the output to the CSV.

Moment.js is used for setting the start and end date to loop through and fast-csv to write the output of the API call to a CSV file.

```
    // load and configure
const piwik = require ('piwik').setup ('placeholderurl', 'XXXXX');

// filesystem requirement
var fs = require('fs');

// fast-csv requirement
var csv = require("fast-csv");

// moment.js requirement
var moment = require('moment');

// variabelen voor het loopen door datums
var a = moment().format('2016-05-12');
var b = moment().format('2016-05-15');

var stream = fs.createWriteStream ('my.csv', {flags: 'a'})


// samenstellen API url

for (var m = moment(a); m.isBefore(b); m.add(1, 'days')) {
    piwik.api (
      {
        method: 'Live.getLastVisitsDetails',
        idSite: 3,
        period: 'day',
        format: 'csv',
        date: moment(m).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
      },
        function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log (err);
                return;
            }
        console.log(data)       
        csv
            .writeToStream(fs.createWriteStream("my.csv"), data, {flags: 'a', headers: true});
        }
    );
}
```

API token and url removed for privacy reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Got rid of the PIWIK API package and decided to use HTTP GET to retrieve the url manually.

The code:

```
// http requirement
var http = require('http');

var request = require('request');

// filesystem requirement
var fs = require('fs');

// moment.js requirement
var moment = require('moment');

// variabelen voor het loopen door datums
var a = moment().format('2016-05-12');
var b = moment().format('2016-05-15');

var m = moment(a);

//var stream = fs.createWriteStream ('my.csv', {flags: 'a'})

// samenstellen API url
for (var m = moment(a); m.isBefore(b); m.add(1, 'days')) {
    request
  .get("http://placeholder.com/?module=API&method=Live.getLastVisitsDetails&idSite=3&period=day&date=" + moment(m).format('YYYY-MM-DD') + "&format=csv&token_auth=placeholdertoken&filter_limit=-1")
  .on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err)
    })
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('data-' + moment(m).format('YYYY-MM-DD') + '.csv'))
  console.log(moment(m).format('YYYY-MM-DD') + " " + "saved")
}
```